# aggrid cell renderer on autoGroupColumnDef flattens tree

Tags: ag-grid

I need to create a custom cell renderer on the hierarchy column in a tree data grid. The problem is that the tree gets flattened.

I've tried assigning a cell renderer on the autoGroupColumnDef:

```
    this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
      headerName: "Organisation Hierarchy",
      cellRendererParams: { suppressCount: true },
      cellRenderer:  'nameCellRenderer'
    };
```

But the tree gets flattened (loses the hierarchy). Here is a plunker example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YsTCsNGIikFY7eelGNJJ?p=preview

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out. Had to add 
`innerRenderer:  'nameCellRenderer'`
in `cellRendererParams`
. I updated the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YsTCsNGIikFY7eelGNJJ?p=preview)